# Make a plot of the nth prime divided by n*log(n) ,for n from 2to1000

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, prime-numbers, logic

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[n, Prime[1000]]/n*log (n), {n, 2, 1000}]]
```

> this is all i can do.

Comment: You're close. Use this `ListPlot[Table[Prime[n]/(n*Log[n]), {n, 2, 1000}]]`.

Comment: @BenIzd `ListPlot` by default plots its data starting from the point 1 on the abscissa. Try `ListPlot[{2, 3, 4}]` as an example. To correct your suggestion: either `ListPlot[Table[Prime[n]/(n*Log[n]), {n, 2, 1000}], DataRange -> {2, 1000}]` or `ListPlot[Table[{n, Prime[n]/(n*Log[n])}, {n, 2, 1000}]]`

Comment: @Roman You're right. It's a subtle tip I missed. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DiscretePlot[Prime[n]/(n Log[n]), {n, 1000}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of `DiscretePlot[]`